# I'm trying to run a rake test ruby / sinatra and its telling me rake aborted! I'm not sure what to do

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rake-test

Here is the what my terminal is showing me..

```
user@Users-MacBook-Pro palindrome_app % bundle exec rake test
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mustermann-1.1.1/lib/mustermann.rb:73:in `new': Hash can't be coerced into Mustermann::Pattern (TypeError)
    from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mustermann-1.1.1/lib/mustermann.rb:70:in `block in new'
    from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mustermann-1.1.1/lib/mustermann.rb:70:in `map'
    from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mustermann-1.1.1/lib/mustermann.rb:70:in `new'
    from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1641:in `compile'
    from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1629:in `compile!'
    from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1271:in `error'
    from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1839:in `<class:Base>'
    from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:894:in `<module:Sinatra>'
    from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.3/lib/sinatra/main.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.3/lib/sinatra/main.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.3/lib/sinatra.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.3/lib/sinatra.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/Desktop/repos/palindrome_app/app.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/user/Desktop/repos/palindrome_app/app.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/Desktop/repos/palindrome_app/test/test_helper.rb:3:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/user/Desktop/repos/palindrome_app/test/test_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/Desktop/repos/palindrome_app/test/site_pages_test.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/user/Desktop/repos/palindrome_app/test/site_pages_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:17:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:17:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `select'
    from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1)
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => test
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: My guess: You're using Ruby 3.0 and that library doesn't support it yet. There's a breaking change when it comes to parsing arguments that has impacted a lot of code that runs fine (with lots of warnings!) in 2.7.

Comment: It's worth checking if there's an [active issue](https://github.com/sinatra/mustermann/issues) on this particular bug. I couldn't see one in a quick search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr: Upgrade `sinatra` to version `2.1.0`.** (Or, downgrade ruby to `v2.7`.)

You are running *old gem versions* (in particular, `sinatra v2.0.3`), with the *latest* version of ruby (`v3.0.0`). You may run into various compatibility problems by doing that, because you could be missing crucial ruby 3.0 compatibility updates from those libraries.

There are [various mentions](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#210--2020-09-05) of ruby 2.7+ keyword deprecation fixes in the `sinatra` changelog.

Specifically, this error:

```
gems/3.0.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1629:in `compile!'
```

Was fixed by [this change](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/pull/1581/files#diff-d91dacd5fa5ae6f9bf2a5597340fdc531421266ba821aa7a5739b941e5677fa9R1641) in [this PR](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/pull/1581), which shipped as part of sinatra `v2.0.8`. Also, [additional fixes](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/pull/1586) were added as part of the `v2.1.0` release.

Comment: Thank you all soo much for your responses !! I updated to Sinatra 2.1.0 and the test ran perfectly !! Thank you all again.